# iOS In-App Purchase invalid product ID iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, in-app

In-App purchase retrieving products data and purchasing are working well on iOS 6. However, on iOS 5.1.1, I receive "invalid product identifier" when trying getting a product data. What can be incompatible here?

Answer (score 1):

Is this hosted content with Apple? If so, hosted content with Apple is only available from iOS 6 upwards.